# Storing and retrieving url links

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 300 url links that I want store, I plan to have 10 xml's, below is my code, how can I store the urls in a xml and retrieve them in this code??  I want to get the coordinates based on the users selection from a list view.

```
public class official extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser1);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());



    }
}
class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you would like to store the URLs in an xml file and not simply use the SQLite database?

Comment: Yes forgive me, I cannot seem to get sqlite to work and at the moment I am not entirely sure how it works, need some time to work on it in the mean time I'd like to try it this way because I have the urls broke into categories and I think it might be more practical.

Comment: Using the SQLite database isn't really that hard. This page gives advice for using the database (as well as other forms of data storage): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html If you take a look there, and google for some tutorials, you ought to get the database going in no-time. And it is a way better way to store data than to mess around with files.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just storing a list of URLs, why don't you just store them as a plain text file, where each line is a new URL. Trying to put the URLs into a database or an XML file just adds extra effort (read: time, processing) when trying to read or write them.